# how could i write a for loop that adds up all the numbers in the array to the totalSnacksEaten variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```js
let snacksEatenPerDay = [3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 2, 2, 4, 8, 2, 5, 3, 3, 1];
let totalSnacksEaten = 0;
for(let i = 0; i<=snacksEatenPerDay ; i++)

totalSnacksEaten = totalSnacksEaten +i
console.log(totalSnacksEaten);
```

i want to modify my code so i could have a result to know the sum of the array in the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you do well in javascript.

```js
let snacksEatenPerDay = [3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 2, 2, 4, 8, 2, 5, 3, 3, 1];
let totalSnacksEaten = 0;

for(let i = 0; i<snacksEatenPerDay.length ; i++){
  totalSnacksEaten = totalSnacksEaten + snacksEatenPerDay[i]
}

console.log(totalSnacksEaten);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you study the basics of javascript and array concept.

```
let snacksEatenPerDay = [3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 2, 2, 4, 8, 2, 5, 3, 3, 1];
let totalSnacksEaten = 0;

for(let i = 0; i<snacksEatenPerDay.length ; i++){
  totalSnacksEaten = totalSnacksEaten  + snacksEatenPerDay[i]
}
console.log(totalSnacksEaten);
```

Comment: You need to change `i<=snacksEatenPerDay.length` to `i<snacksEatenPerDay.length`. you will be good to go

Comment: @CodeManiac Fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you...

```js
let snacksEatenPerDay = [3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 2, 2, 4, 8, 2, 5, 3, 3, 1];
let totalSnacksEaten = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < snacksEatenPerDay.length ; i++){
  totalSnacksEaten += snacksEatenPerDay[i];
}
console.log(totalSnacksEaten);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), which takes a callback function that is executed upon each iteration of the array and reduces the array to a single output value. That callback function will automatically be passed several arguments, but the first two (accumulator and current value) are all you need for this:

```js
let snacksEatenPerDay = [3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 2, 2, 4, 8, 2, 5, 3, 3, 1];
let totalSnacksEaten = snacksEatenPerDay.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
  return accumulator + currentValue;
});

console.log(totalSnacksEaten );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a few ways, but you might want to read up on javascript's reduce function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Here's an example:

```
// ES5 way
let snacksEatenPerDay = [3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 2, 2, 4, 8, 2, 5, 3, 3, 1];
let totalSnacksEaten = snacksEatenPerDay.reduce(function(acc, value) {
    return acc + value;
}, 0);

console.log(totalSnacksEaten);

// ES6 way
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;

let totalSnacksEatenReducer = snacksEatenPerDay.reduce(reducer);

console.log(totalSnacksEatenReducer);
```